# Why is my XPath not working?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Trying to grab the **first set** of elements between tags with the class name "a".

```
<div>
<div class = "a"></div>
<div class = "b"></div> <----
<div class = "b"></div> <----
<div class = "b"></div> <----
<div class = "a"></div>
<div class = "b"></div>
<div class = "b"></div>
<div class = "b"></div>
<div class = "b"></div>
<div class = "a"></div>
...

//div[@class='a']/following-sibling::div[@class='a'][1]/preceding-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[@class='a']]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: your xpath seems to have nothing to do with the posted code example?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath is being evaluated for *all* `div[@class='a']` elements (note the `//`).

All you have to do is restrict it to the first one:

```
(//div[@class='a'])[1]/following-sibling::div[@class='a'][1]/preceding-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[@class='a']]
```

Comment: For some reason I'm only getting 2 elements back instead of 3.

Comment: I get 3 with your sample. Can you share (simple is fine) *complete* XML that you have the problem with?

Comment: I tested his xpath, replacing `a` with `wisfb_scheduleGroupTitle`, and it worked.

Comment: I just tested in Chrome as well and it's working, but not in my scraper's function. Guess that's a different issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this xpath will work for you:

```
//div/section/div[count(preceding-sibling::div[@class='wisfb_scheduleGroupTitle'])=1]/preceding-sibling::div[@class!='wisfb_scheduleGroupTitle']
```

Tested against the page, and verified it worked.